# Place LinearLayout below FrameLayout with ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I want to place a LinearLayout below a FrameLayout which contains a ListView, but the content of the LinearLayout is not shown.
I also tried this out with a surrounding LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout without success.
The FrameLayout cannot be changed to different layout type!
The LinearLayout below will be shown and hidden programmatically.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/framelayout_container" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/content_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:padding="0dp" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/description_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/description_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/included_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/below_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#33b5e5" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/below_layout"
        layout="@layout/below_layout"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas how to get this work?

Comment: When you say the "content of the LinearLayout," which LL are you referring to?  Also, do you realize that that last LL's height is 0dp?  That is probably the problem.

Comment: Maybe take the linear layout out and make it a footer view of your listview?

Comment: @NightlyNexus the 0dp was the problem, didn't realized that because i tried out some different approaches...thanks !

Comment: @DeveloperPaul i will try this also and give you feedback.

Comment: @DeveloperPaul footer is not a solution in this case, because footer is only visible at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your FrameLayout is set to match the parent width and height, so it will leave no room for the LinearLayout beneath it. You would need to revise it to use its layout_height set to wrap_content, and change the inner ListView to do the same.

Comment: does it make sense to set the height of a listview to wrap_content?

Comment: You can, yes, although it still may cause problems since you have it wrapped in a FrameLayout.  The other issue you'll run into is that you have a `ListView` and a `LinearLayout` both inside of the `FrameLayout`, so they will effectively sit on top of one another.

Comment: the framelayout with its contents is intended (quickreturn-view).